# Multiple Cascading Delete

Tags: custom-list, lookup-column, spfieldlookupvalue, cascade-delete

I have 3 lists, lets say A, B, and C

I have a lookup in a column from B to A

I also lookup in a column from C to B.

I have the column lookups in B and C as Cascading Delete.

If I delete A, I know B will be deleted, but will C be deleted as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are maintaining "Cascading Delete" lookup in between the two lists such as "B" & "C", The removal of list item from the "B" removing the related item in the list "C".

*If you don't want to remove the item from "C" list. Change it to "Restrict Delete".*

Please check this link for more detail:
[Cascade and Restrict Delete](http://adicodes.com/list-cascade-and-restrict-delete/)

Comment: yes, removing B will Remove C and I understand the basics of cascading delete. <br /><br />
What I would like to know is because there is a lookup between A and B AND a lookup between B and C, if I delete A (I am not deleting B), will B and C be deleted or just B?

Comment: If you are maintaining "Cascading delete" between both "A&B" and "B&C", it'll will remove the matching items from both "B" and "C". Else if you are maintaining "Cascade delete" between just "A&B" and "Restrict Delete" between "B&C", then it'll remove the matching item from "B" alone.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark your post as an answer.  That's what I thought should have happened.  I have a set up now that used to delete B, C if I remove A.  Now, it's only deleting A and B.  So I have to figure out what happened.  From What I understand, it doesn't matter what lookup is connecting A and B, if there is a different column lookup between B and C, it's should delete all.